# Hard Drive Advance Format 512e Compatibility with 4K Native OS

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, windows-server-2012, advanced-format

I would like to understand the compatibility of the Advance Format drives with existing OS's, particularly if the Hard Drive has 512 emulation (AF 512e).

I understand the basics of how the 512 Emulation works on the hard drives, but I have not seen anything to clarify the behavior of such drives in a compatible operating system.

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848035%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), under Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008, they are compatible with the 512e emulation (and having logical sectors of 512 bytes and physical sectors of 4096 bytes).  It also shows that Windows 8 and Server 2012 have native 4K sector support, but what happens when you put a AF 512e hard drive in a computer where the OS natively supports 4K sectors?

- Will the AF 512e hard drive operate as a native 4K hard drive in a scenario where the OS supports a 4K?
- Or will the 512 Emulation still make the OS believe that the sectors are 512 bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emulation is done in the hard drive, so the operating systems treat it as a 512 sector drive. They have no control over the emulation process.

Answer (score 0):

- Will the AF 512e hard drive operate as a native 4K hard drive in a scenario where the OS supports a 4K?

No manufacturers formats hdd's (enable emulation mode) 512e for maximum compability (except a few models ready 4k at factory exit). Even 4kn so OS will use it as 512 byte sector if emulation enabled.

- Or will the 512 Emulation still make the OS believe that the sectors are 512 bytes?

Yes 512e OS believe 512 byte sector hdd.

But you can change between 512e and 4kn. Only old (512n) drives will not change to 4kn